# NodeJS Asychronous I/O Execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

As far as I understand, although there is apparently a 'helper' thread, Node.js runs in a single thread, therefore, each operation in the Event Loop stack runs one after another and other operations and queued while Node performs asynchronous I/O in the background, this way the server is able to perform other actions while doing non-blocking I/O without the need to create wasteful multiple threads, the I/O is finished and the it's associated callback is pulled into the Event Loop queue, and that's the big thing about Node.

However, in many articles I've ready, is not clear if asynchronous I/O operations run in parallel with other I/O operations in I/O a separate thread or process or if each requested I/O operation runs one after another in a helper thread while the Event Loop performs other actions. And after reading the phrase "Everything runs in parallel except your code" this makes me even more confuse.

The question is, multithread or not multithread? If each asynchronous operation runs in a separate thread, doesn't it have use as much resources as an Apache server would?

Comment: Therefore the Node process in the system itself is Single-threaded while Node delegates I/O/Asynchronous operations to the OS, which in turn opens new threads to execute each operation? Is that what is called a 'thread poll'?

Comment: FS operations generally are the only requests that utilize a thread pool (this is handled inside libuv and not node.js though). Everything else is done on the main thread. Network I/O in particular is all handled by polling sockets for activity via the suitable polling mechanism for each OS (e.g. epoll on Linux, kqueue on BSD/OS X, IOCP on Windows, etc.).

Comment: @Lhaer: That's not what `thread pool` is. Thread pools are something completely different. This technique is called **non-blocking I/O** or **event loop**.

Answer (score 3):

Node is, essentially, non-multithreaded.  The asynchronicity goes deeper than Node, deeper than libuv, and even deeper than the facilities (`epoll`, `kqueue`, `IOCP`, etc.) that libuv uses.

When the kernel gets an async request it does not fire up another thread of execution. Instead, it adds it to a simple list of "things to watch out for."  If a process makes a network read request, for instance, the kernel will make an entry on that list.  It's something like "hey, next time there is a read request that looks like this, let the process know about it."  After making this entry, the kernel returns control back to the process and both go on their merry way.  The only thing that survives is the data on the list.

The kernel is informed of a network read event via [hardware interrupts.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)  Using an interrupt, the processor yanks the kernel into a special loop -- stopping anything it's doing at the moment -- and tells it about the event.  The kernel then checks against its list of outstanding requests, and (in the kevent AIO case) sends a similar interrupt (in the form of a signal) to the process to let it know about the network read.  So, no threads.  Just interruptions.

Well, this is a bit of a simplification: in the non-AIO kevent and epoll cases, after the kernel gets a network read it'll just put it on an event list.  The process periodically checks that event list to see if something came in for it.

Also, from the kernel view, this is how all I/O works.  The big difference is that the kernel isn't requiring the process to wait for the kernel to get back to it.

There is actually [a little more complexity](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html) in libuv as non-network requests (and DNS requests, which are special, painful forms of network requests) are handled by threads.  This is because the kernel facilities for making those asynchronous are generally not so great, if they exist at all.

Comment: There is at least one language where disk I/O is handled asynchronously without threads: Tcl (tcl, which predates js, has a built-in event loop). But I know the code implementing it is messy and full of #defines for OS specific stuff: almost half of which is Unix alone in all the various flavors. And then there's Windows (the Windows overlapped-io API is actually quite nice and better than some Unixen but is very different from everyone else's). It can be done but takes a lot of effort.

Comment: Good example, although Tcl didn't come with fileevents originally (and didn't until some time after Tk brought an event loop with it).  On (most) Unix it's built around a `select()` call.  `select()` has been around since 1983ish and is the basis for many C-language libraries with event loops: Xt, Qt, Gtk etc.

Comment: Yes, the core of tcl's event loop is `select()`. For disk I/O on Unixen that's not Linux it uses kqueue. Not sure what it uses for linux. Probably aio.

Answer (score 2):

It's not multithreaded with one minor exception. Let's talk about that exception later. First, lets see why things can happen in parallel but not multithreaded.

### Waiting for I/O

When you send something over the network, for example, making a http request, waiting for a http response to complete or waiting for mysql to respond your software is not doing anything.

So, how can the network work if your software is not doing anything? *(sorry if this is obvious but pointing out the obvious is usually what makes it obvious)*.

### Some things happen outside the CPU

First, most of the network is outside your CPU. You have your network card buffering data going out and coming in. You have the electrons in the network cable or photons in space/air vibrating according to the signal sent by networking equipment. You have your router, your ISP, the server on the other side of the planet etc.

All the above needs to be processed in order for your http request to return data. In most languages, while all the above is happening, your code will not be doing anything.

Not so in javascript. When an I/O request is made, instead of waiting for the data to return the interpreter will simply register a callback you supply to execute when the data finally gets here. Now that that's done, other code can execute. Maybe some other data requested earlier is now here and that callback can be executed. Maybe a `setTimeout` has expired and it's time to call that callback.

So multiple things can happen in parallel, most of it outside your process, a lot of it outside your CPU, some of it on another machine which may even be on the other side of the planet. While that's going on, javascript allows you to run some code.

### The exception: disk I/O

The exception to this is disk I/O. At the lowest level (actually, next-to-lowest) C exposes only synchronous functions like `fread()`, `fwrite()` for I/O. Reading network packets are also technically synchronous. The difference is that the network doesn't respond immediately so the networking code has lots of time to spare waiting for packets. It is in between these reads and writes that javascript runs your code. But the filesystem will happily tell you that data is immediately available. So, unlike the networking code, the code reading from disk will spend most of its time being busy.

There are several work-arounds to this. Some OS even have asynchronous API to read from disk. The node.js developers have decided to handle this situation by spawning another thread to do disk I/O. So for disk I/O it is parallel because it's multithreaded.

Comment: The most detailed, low-level explanation I've ever written on this subject can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883525/i-know-that-callback-function-runs-asynchronously-but-why/29885509#29885509