# Is it safe to listen to an event AFTER registering it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm new to NodeJS, and I'm learning how it works with streams.
Reading a book I found this sample code:

```
var CountStream = require('./countstream');
var countStream = new CountStream('book');
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.manning.com', function(res) {
    res.pipe(countStream);
});

countStream.on('total', function(count) {
    console.log();
});
```

In this code snippet we're calling `http.get` method and then waiting for the callback (**Part 1**).

On the next line we're listening for `total` event (**Part 2**).

**Question:** What if a delay happens between Part 1 and Part 2, so the Part 1's callback executes first (before Part 2 starts listening to  to `total` event. Is it true that the first chunk(s) of data will be lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you're **not "waiting"** for the callback. The callback is **asynchronous**, and will be executed after the `http.get` function has returned. Part 2 will be executed before the callback functin (Part 1) is invoked.

It is totally safe to construct an asynchronous event emitter and register event handlers only after the construction (as long as it happens synchronously), as the events will only be emitted in the next turn of the event loop.

See also [Hidden threads in Javascript/Node that never execute user code: is it possible, and if so could it lead to an arcane possibility for a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30906228/1048572).

Comment: What if there's a delay between part 1 and part 2. In the answer you provided for the referenced question, you stated that the callbacks wont execute until this function (container) finish its execution. Am I understand right?

Comment: @mehrandvd: It's fine as long as this delay is synchronous - it can be as long as it wants. The *complete current turn* of the event loop will run to completion (including the delay and the event handler registration) before the events are emitted. You only must ensure that the handlers are not attached asynchronously.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting point of view. Seeing the problem having event loop in mind makes it more sensible.

Comment: To echo what @Bergi said, in this code there is no way that the `total` event could ever happen before you register the event listener.

Comment: @MattBrowne yep, that's interesting. In languages like C# or Java you should take care of these mistakes, but here, it's great.

Comment: @mehrandvd as well as the above apparently parse time is not the same as execution time.