# Does it matter if you use socket.connect() before or after setting handlers in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io-client` for `react`, I do my setup inside an `useEffect` statement and wondered if i should add handlers before or after calling `connect()`, or if it even mattered ?

My assumption is that you setup your handlers before you're ready to make a connection, therefore having a code similar to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onConnectionHandler() {
        setSioConnected(true);
    }

    sio.on("connection", onConnectionHandler);
    sio.connect();

    return () => {
        sio.off("connection", onConnectionHandler);
        sio.disconnect();
    }
}, []);
```

Swapping the `.on()` & `.connect()` statements could make sense too.

Is there a "right" way to do it ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with react. The behaviour of socketio is the same regardless whether this is happening in a react effect or anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099598/is-it-safe-to-listen-to-an-event-after-registering-it) answer your question? It was written for nodejs, but works the same in the browser

Comment: @Bergi, Yes, the behavior is supposedly the same, this was just context, it is obviously not the point of my question.

Edit, i read too fast, my bad, it does indeed answer the question. My apologies, thanks for providing this link !