# How do I safely use an AJV schema for concurrent validations?

Tags: node.js, typescript, concurrency, jsonschema, ajv

I have five years experience in programming but I am very new to NodeJS and TypeScript.

According to [their documentation](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html), the normal way to use AJV for synchronous validation in TypeScript is to use the return of `AJV#compile` as both a function and an object.

```
import { AJV } from 'ajv';
// I am loading my schema from an adjacent file
import * as create_search_response from './create_search.schema.json';

const ajv = new AJV();
const validator = ajv.compile(create_search_response);

function throwUnlessObjectIsValid(obj: any) {
    if (!validator(obj)) {
        // assume at least one error
        throw validator.errors?.pop();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that we use the global value of `validator.errors` to store and retrieve the error info, similar to `errno` in C.

What if I perform validation in two threads simultaneously? Wouldn't the errors get mixed up? I have looked at their [asynchronous validation](https://ajv.js.org/guide/async-validation.html) system, and it would solve my problem with promise-based API, but I'm very confused about the details of keywords. It seems to require that I change the JSON schema itself.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Node is singlethreaded ...there are no "two threads simultaneously" ... Asynchronous validation is a possiblity, where certain properties of the object to be validated need to be checked for instance against a database

Comment: @derpirscher so a node server can only fulfill requests one at a time? That seems like a huge limitation.

Comment: No of course not. Read for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982489/how-does-asynchronous-programming-work-in-a-single-threaded-programming-model or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007636/how-javascript-single-threaded-and-asynchronous  to learn about how the node runtime handles this